# Yum problems with easy apache - The server’s system package manager, ‘YUM’, failed.?

Tags: yum, rpm

I keep getting the following error on easy appache

**!! The server’s system package manager, ‘YUM’, failed. !**

```
!! 
This is the command that failed: yum -y install gettext automake19 libstdc++.x86_64 libpng-devel readline-devel openssl libpng-dev zlib-devel autoconf261 libidn-devel gmake libidn libXpm openssl-devel automake coreutils patch libltdl3-devel libltdl libopenssl0.9.7-static-devel readline-dev libtool-ltdl-devel libXpm-devel sed libXpm-dev lsof krb5-dev flex glibc-dev expat-dev krb5-devel libstdc++-devel.x64_64 xorg-x11-devel libtool-ltdl libssl-dev pam-devel libopenssl0-devel zlib1-devel expat-devel libopenssl0-dev glibc-devel expat gcc-c++ zlib bison libjpeg-devel libtool-libltdl-devel libtool openssl-dev libopenssl0 libz-devel libjpeg-dev pam-dev fileutils libltdl-devel libopenssl0.9.7-devel e2fsprogs-devel ca_root_nss make libstdc++-dev.x86_64 libX11-devel libstdc++-devel.x86_64 gd cpp xorg-x11-dev gcc ssl-dev lex autoconf !!

!! 
Since EasyApache was unable to resolve it automatically you should: 1) Manually run the failed YUM command (shown above) via SSH 2) See if your particular error is addressed at http://go.cpanel.net/eaerror 3) Resolve the YUM problem manually 4) Re-run EasyApache !!

!! Please visit http://go.cpanel.net/eaerror for help with this error. !!

!! Restoring original working apache !!
```

I keep getting these errors

I try the following

> yum clean headers
>
> yum clean packages
>
> yum clean metadata
>
> yum clean dbcache
>
> yum clean all

and whe i try

> yum -y update

```
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
httpd-mmn = 20051115 is needed by mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64
** Found 3 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
frontpage-2002-SR1.2.i386 has missing requires of libexpat.so.0
mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-2.el6_1.4.x86_64 has missing requires of httpd-mmn = ('0', '20051115', 
None)
sendmail-cf-8.14.4-8.el6.noarch has missing requires of sendmail = ('0', '8.14.4', '8.el6')
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with: yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx
```

When i do a **yum check** i get

```
yum check
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
frontpage-2002-SR1.2.i386 has missing requires of libexpat.so.0
mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-2.el6_1.4.x86_64 has missing requires of httpd-mmn = ('0', '20051115', None)
msttcorefonts-2.5-1.noarch is obsoleted by msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.noarch
sendmail-cf-8.14.4-8.el6.noarch has missing requires of sendmail = ('0', '8.14.4', '8.el6')
Error: check all
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It think there may be me some previous incomplete transactions by using yum, try following 
commands

**yum-complete-transactions**

**yum remove yum-utils**

**yum install yum-utils**

Comment: Nops still Error: Protected multilib versions: libstdc++-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64 != libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686

Comment: try yum install libstdc++-devel.i686 or update the same package instead of install, some oracle software requires 32 bit packages also along with 64 bit , so try installing both

Comment: Nice one out of the way now ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
libz.so.1 is needed by libxml2-2.7.6-12.el6_4.1.i686
httpd-mmn = 20051115 is needed by mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

We just spent several hours fighting this exact problem and found the solution was completely unrelated to the error message... making it that much harder to find.

Our solution: The installed version of cPanel and WHM was out of date.

We went into the WHM menus and clicked `Upgrade to Latest Version` which took 10 minutes or so and then the EasyApache install worked perfectly.

Hope this helps.